# Accessing the list of files from the specific folder in google Drive using oAuth token in R

Tags: r, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to access the google drive using oAuth token. I have created the access token and tried to access the particular folder using the code block given below

```
sampleDrive <- GET("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3/files/folderId",
                  add_headers("Authorization" = new_access_token_drive))
```

But I'm unable to get the list of files along with the corresponding ID in that folder. Can anyone help me to sort this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: How are you creating this  access token and whats the error?

Comment: I don't get any error. I need to know how to access the list of files in a specific folder using the folder Id in R using oAuth token